# File ended while scanning use of \abx@aux@cite

Tags: errors

I get the following message when I compile the file.

> File ended while scanning use of \abx@aux@cite

I have already deleted the aux-file but I still get this message. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: if the error comes back when you delete the aux then you probably have an error in a \cite command somewhere, hard to give specific advice if you show no code and only a fragment of the error message.

Comment: look in the aux file you will see a line like  `\abx@aux@cite{0}{hmmmm...`  with more `{` than `}` you should be able to tell from the partial line which `\cite` is at fault

Comment: I looked intro the aux file and I get this message for almost all sources that I have cited (I have cited over 200 sources). I didn't have this problem until recently, maybe two or three weeks ago.

Comment: You will have a `abx@cite` line for every cite but one will have a missing `}` because of an error in your document (the full log would also show which one has the problem) Presumably an error in a `\cite` you added at that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only shown a small fragment of the error message, and none of your source.

The `.aux` file has a missing `}` and the full message on the terminal will look something like

```
Runaway argument?
{sun2023survey \abx@aux@segm {0}{0}{sun2023survey} \@writefile {toc}{\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \abx@aux@cite.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.34 \begin{document}
                     
?
```

where the first context line will show the line that has the `{` that has no matching `}`

That line will have been generated by a command such as `\textcite{sun2023survey}` but an error made the aux data be corrupted.

This means that if you delete the `.aux` file so that you do not get the runaway argument error, you will have an error in the main document on a `\cite` or related command. The error message for that error will also help pinpoint which citation is at fault.